# How to turn text and a value from an array into a String?

Tags: java

Basically the program is pretty simple:

it takes a list of names and makes each player verse every player but only once..

So ceri would play 5 games in a row but what I want to happen is it to be random..

```
public class hatpicking {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] Names = { "Ceri", "Matthew", "Harry", "Lewis", "Kwok", "James"};


    List<String> Matches = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < Names.length; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j <Names.length; j++){
            if(Names[i].equals(Names[j])){
                continue;
            }else{

                Matches.add(Names[i] + " v" Names[j]);
                    System.out.println(Names[i] + " v " + Names[j]);
                }
            }   
        }       
    }       
}
```

I'm sure there is an easier way to randomise stuff but i'm only getting back into Programming so I need the work where ever I can...

Pretty much I want to assign:
                    (Names[i] + " v " Names[j]);
to the ArrayList - Matches but obviously

```
                Matches.add(Names[i] + " v" Names[j]);
```

does not work, any hints?

Comment: Does it work? If no, what is wrong? If yes, what is your question?

Comment: How would I add Name[i] + "v" Names[j] to Matches as it doesnt work @tich

Comment: Please describe in more detail *how* it does not work. What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: @Tichodroma sorry, forgot to tag you

Comment: the expected result would be that the values of Names[i] " v " Names[j] would be added to the Matches ArrayList as a string

Comment: The expected *output* vs. the actual *output*.

Answer (score 2):

`Matches.add(Names[i] + " v" Names[j]);`

should be

`Matches.add(Names[i] + " v" + Names[j]);`

Comment: @CeriWestcott You should learn to read and correct errors. A good IDE might also help.

Comment: @usama8800 I use Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Eran's answer is correct and will fix your bug. However, on a side note, a word about Java naming conventions. In Java, class names should always start with a capital letter, so `class hatpicking` should be `class Hatpicking`. In addition, variable names should start with a lowercase letter, so `Names` and `Matches`should be `names` and `matches`.

Comment: THANK YOU! I literally could not remember if it was vice verse, it's been playing on my mind for a while haha!

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: Your welcome :) @usama8800, I don't have enough rep to comment on other people's posts :P

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you just want to randomize the matches. So just use the existing code you have and just shuffle the output.

For for best shuffling results use see **Shuffling** section in this link. http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomMatch {

  public void matchGenerator() { 
      List<String> availablePlayers = Arrays.asList("Ceri", "Matthew", "Harry", "Lewis", "Kwok", "James");
      List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
      int MAX_PLAYERS = availablePlayers.size();
      for(int i=0; i<MAX_PLAYERS; i++) {
          String homePlayer = availablePlayers.get(i);
          for(int j=i+1; j<MAX_PLAYERS; j++) {
              String awayPlayer = availablePlayers.get(j);
              if(!homePlayer.equals(awayPlayer)) {
                  String match = homePlayer + " vs. " + awayPlayer;
                  matches.add(match);   
              }
          }
      }
      System.out.println("Match List\n");
      for(String match : matches) 
          System.out.println(match);
      shuffle(matches);
      System.out.println("Shuffled Match List\n");
      for(String match : matches) 
          System.out.println(match);

  }

  public void shuffle(List<String> matches) { 
      long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Collections.shuffle(matches, new Random(seed));
      seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Collections.shuffle(matches, new Random(seed));
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      RandomMatch randomMatch = new RandomMatch();
      randomMatch.matchGenerator();
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems way over the top for a simple task:

I finish this off here..:

Comment: https://scontent-a-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/10382869_10203343480684571_4145375306278338405_n.jpg